# Reference to object property JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, reference

I've got a problem with reference to an object. I don't understand why in function animal I can't get acces to cat-object.

```js
const cat ={
  price: 200,
  dollarsSec: 4,
  quantity: 0
};

let image = document.getElementById("cat-shop");
image.addEventListener('click', event => {
  let parseName = event.target.id.toString();
  parseName = parseName.replace("-shop","");
  buy(parseName);
});

function buy (animal) {
  console.log(animal); // This return "cat"
  console.log(animal.price); // This returns undefined. I want cat.price
}
```

```css
#cat-shop {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="cat-shop"></div>
```

Comment: `parseName` is *the string `'cat'`*, not the object referred to by the name `cat`.

Comment: So what do I need to do to get reference to that object?

Comment: There are many options, probably the most sensible is to have an object mapping names to the objects, e.g. `const animals = { cat };`. Then you can use a property lookup to go from the string name to the object.

Comment: It works !!! Thanks !!!